# the design of a class consisting of a set of @statisticmethod functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods

While reading a python project, I found the author wrote a lot of classes with the following manner, i.e., a given class only consists of a set of functions of `@statisticmethod`, such as `class readingUtils` in the following. My question is that does this design belong to a specific type of design pattern, or does it have any specific design consideration?

```
class readingUtils(object):

    @staticmethod
    def function1(var1, var2):
        ----
    
    @staticmethod
    def function2(var1, var2):
        -----
```

Comment: I'd note that this probably not idiomatic python, and I'd bet whoever wrote this spent a lot of time writing Java or C#, where you are forced to do this. The most natural way to do this in Python is just a bunch of module-level functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a variant of the "singleton" pattern. It's just a way of collecting functions into a coherent group, without having any shared state.